# Make lower case upper and upper case lower in a string

Tags: c#

I have been struggling on using .ToUpper and .ToLower to convert words in strings to the opposite case.

Example 1:

```
Input: hello WORLD
Output: HELLO world
```

Example 2:

```
Input: THIS is A TEST
Output: this IS a test
```

Comment: Do you need to accommodate words of mixed case? What about punctuation?

Comment: Can you share you're existing code so we can see what problems you're having?

Comment: No mixed case words and no punctuation @JohnathanBarclay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
string input = "hello WORLD";
string output = "";
foreach(char c in input ){
    output += Char.IsUpper(c) ? Char.ToLower(c) : Char.ToUpper(c);
}
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

The code above inverts the case of every char in the string, so doesn't matter if its camelCase, PascalCase or just upper/lower case.

Comment: +1 You can simplify this by `output += Char.IsUpper(c) ? Char.ToLower(c) : c;` since you already know that `c` is upper case.

Comment: If you're taking this approach you should use `StringBuilder`; reallocating a new string at each iteration will be inefficient for large inputs.

Comment: @eglease It only enters in `Char.ToUpper(c)` if its lowercase, so it makes it uppercase. If i change it like you suggest it, everything will be lowercase.

Comment: `c` will stay whatever case it is.  since you check to see if it is Upper case, it will stay upper case.

Comment: @eglease By your logic, how is it possible to convert a lowercase character to uppercase? Have you tested the code you suggested?

Comment: @eglease here, i test it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WYxprb everything will be lowercase like i said.

Comment: You are right.  I misunderstood the logic that you always have to switch.  Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

## C#

```cs
string a = "hello WORLD";

string b = new string(a.Select(_ => char.IsLower(_) ? char.ToUpper(_) : char.ToLower(_)).ToArray());
```

Comment: Very Ellegant! :D Just edit it to make the syntax highlighting work.

Comment: You may want to replace that `_` (suggestion: use `c` for character), now that it might be seen as a [discard operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards)

Answer (score 3):

Define a function that converts a single-cased word to the opposite case:

```
string ConvertCase(string word)
{
    if (word.All(char.IsUpper)) return word.ToLower();
    if (word.All(char.IsLower)) return word.ToUpper();
    return word;
}
```

Then split your sentence into words, convert each word and join back into a string:

```
var convertedSenetence = string.Join(' ', sentence.Split(' ').Select(ConvertCase));
```

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FFKybQ)

---

Of course this can be inlined if you prefer:

```
var convertedSenetence = string.Join(' ', sentence
    .Split(' ')
    .Select(word =>
        word.All(char.IsUpper) ? word.ToLower() :
        word.All(char.IsLower) ? word.ToUpper() :
        word));
```